# Avoid overwriting of a source code

Tags: sourcecode

Is there a way to protect some part of a LaTeX-Code to avoid overwriting? (Cause I want to allocate the code to someone who shouldn't "touch" some parts of the source code.)

Edit:

```
% Begin: don't touch!!
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=26mm, bottom=17mm} 

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mdframed}   
\usepackage{paralist}    

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\columnsep{5mm}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{black!60}{\raisebox{0.5mm}{\rule{1.8mm}{1.8mm}}}}
\newcommand{\zitiert}[1]{\flqq{#1}\frqq}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*}

\addtokomafont{section}{\large}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\setlength\fboxsep{1.75mm}%
      \colorbox{black!15}{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{%
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
          \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}%
    }}}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}%
}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \makebox[10mm][r]{\thesection\autodot\hspace{5mm}}
}
\makeatother

% End: don't touch!!

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some random text....
\lipsum[14]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The part from '% Begin: Don't touch!!' to '% End: Don't touch!!' should be "read-only"..

Comment: What do you mean with protect? Read-only files are a simple solution.

Comment: TeX code behaves like any other program code. It is stored in pure text files without any annotations. So no, it is not possible to protect parts of the code from modifications. But you can put the part that should not be modified into a separate file `nottobemodified.tex` and include it with `\input{nottobemodified}`. When the file is returned, you can use your original version of `nottobemodified` and also check with some text-comparision tool, whether your colleague's version is changed compared to yours.

Comment: could you please add an example of what do you want to protect?

Comment: Classical method: `% Don't  don't  don't  touch this part!`).  Or may be the opposite that gernot suggest: send `tobemodified.tex` while `main.tex` (with `\input{tobemodified}`) is not shared, or it is flagged as read-only in the OS and in the comments (e.g: `% Don't  don't  don't  edit this file !!!`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put the stuff between `% Begin: don't touch!!` and `% End: don't touch!!` into a file `myclass.cls`.
2. In `myclass.cls`, replace `\documentclass` by `\LoadClass` and `\usepackage` by `\RequirePackage`.
3. In `myclass.cls`, remove `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Now `myclass.cls` looks as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\LoadClass[fontsize=8.5pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{helvet}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=26mm, bottom=17mm} 

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage{multicol} 
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{mdframed}   
\RequirePackage{paralist}    

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\columnsep{5mm}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{black!60}{\raisebox{0.5mm}{\rule{1.8mm}{1.8mm}}}}
\newcommand{\zitiert}[1]{\flqq{#1}\frqq}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*}

\addtokomafont{section}{\large}
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\setlength\fboxsep{1.75mm}%
      \colorbox{black!15}{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{%
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
          \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}%
    }}}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}%
}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \makebox[10mm][r]{\thesection\autodot\hspace{5mm}}
}
```

4. Change the original document to

   ```
   \documentclass{myclass}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
   Some random text....
   \lipsum[14]
   \end{multicols}
   \end{document}
   ```

Then tell your colleague not to change `myclass.cls`, or just don't use his copy but yours.

Comment: This is a good way to solve my problem! Thank you:)

Comment: Don't forget to add a license to the class. You can use one, that does not allow changes without changing the identifiers, e.g., [lppl](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl/). ;-)